# Can you check multiple strings in a while statement?

Tags: java, while-loop

I was wondering if it was possible to check for multiple strings to be true in one while statement. The || operator doesn't work and I can't think of another way to make this possible.

Even though I know the statement bellow isn't possible, I want another statement with the same functionality.

```
while (!color1.equals("Red")) || (!color2.equals("Green"))
```

Comment: what about wrapping your entire condition in parentheses: `while ((!color1.equals("Red")) || (!color2.equals("Green")))`

Comment: 1) To answer your question - yes: of *COURSE* you can evaluate more than one boolean expression in a while statement (using "or" or "and").  2) I suspect you really meant "&&" in this particular example (i.e. "loop until EITHER "Red" or "Green")...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is not quite clear to me so I'll give two possible answers.

If at least one condition must be met then you should use `||` operator (be careful with your parentheses by the way - they should wrap both conditions):

```
// at least one condition is met 
while ((!color1.equals("Red")) || (!color2.equals("Green"))) {
  // do something
}
```

Otherwise, if both conditions must be met, instead of `||` you need to use `&&` operator.

```
// both conditions are met
while ((!color1.equals("Red")) && (!color2.equals("Green"))) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Needs another set of parentheses to fully enclose both conditions (as you said...?)

Comment: @RaviPatel My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.